# Click an item from database displayed in listview

Tags: java, android

```
package at.thesis.ticmip;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Mainadminvdictionary extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    private String ddct = Databaseadapter.dtbldctnry;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_vdictionary);

        SQLiteDatabase db= openOrCreateDatabase(Databaseadapter.DATABASE_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE, null); 


        try {

            Cursor c= db.rawQuery("select * from Ddictionary", null);
              //Looping through all rows


            if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        String dss = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("disease"));
                        results.add(dss);
                    }while (c.moveToNext());
                } 
            }           
        } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
      } finally {
            db.close();
      } 



      ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
              android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
          setListAdapter(adapter);

      getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      }



      }
```

i have my code here that will show the data and display in listview my problem now is how can i click an item by its id? I tried using protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {} but its not working

Comment: Overriding onListItemClick is what you need, you just need to figure out why does not work

Comment: What do you mean by 'id'? Position on `ListView` or primary key in DB ?

Comment: **"I tried using protected void onListItemClick(...) {} but its not working"** : Don't just say things like "it's not working" - post the code you tried for that method.

Comment: protected void onListItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    
    
      if (position == 0) {
       Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mainuserstop10.class);
       startActivity(intent);
       }
  
  
  
 }

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - there's an 'edit' option at the bottom left of your question - use that to edit the question and add the code. Also, explain what "doesn't work" means - does it crash or does it simply do nothing?

Comment: If you want PK on click, then I think its better to use custom list adapter. Then tag id on each of it row in `listview`'s `getview` method. You can use `Hashmap` or data structure something like that, to keep id and disease name together. I suggest you to study custom `listview`

Comment: Use a SimpleCursorAdapter and you will have primary key out of the box

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


            }
        });
```

Comment: Your suggestion is not necessary when using a `ListActivity` which has its own convenience / helper methods. In this case, `onListItemClick(...)` is automatically used to set the `OnItemClickListener` of the `Listview`.

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
                if (position == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Mainadminvdictionary.this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Mainadminvdictionary.this, Mainuserstop10.class); startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
```